# MVC/MVP framework to develop Winform/Wpf/Metro style application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, model-view-controller

I am looking for a good MVC / MVP framework for developing windows application in .net. It would be great if the framework supports Winform, Wpf and Metro style application. Though the requirement is little bizarre, but I really want to make the View part of the application very flexible, so that most of the code base can be reused with different presentation layers technology!

I have seen MVC# and AFAIK it supports winforms, but not wpf and metro style apps. On the other hand PureMVC supports wpf but not winforms.

Is there any such framework in the market? A opensource one will be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Prism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx

Although it does not support WinForms, it DOES support WPF (for desktop apps), Silverlight and Windows Phone.

BTW, why do you need WinForms when you can just use WPF? If you want to reuse existing WinForms controls you can always use it within WPF:
http://www.keyvan.ms/host-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf

So you if you want you can have a WPF window/control container (which doesn't really matter) and have WinForms controls/logic inside...

Comment: +1. I hardly could imagine framework supporting both WinForms and WPF.